# You can select tags to ignore

Tags: discussion, tags, spoilers

When you are browsing through the questions list, in the sidebar to the right there are a couple of text boxes labeled "Favorite Tags" and "Ignored Tags".  By adding tags here you can alter the way the questions tagged that way appear.

For instance, lets say that Iron Man 3 just came out, but you haven't seen it yet.  If you don't want anything spoiled, you can add the [iron-man-3](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron-man-3) tag to your ignored tags.  Now, any question tagged with Iron Man 3 will be grayed out and hard to see, making it easier to look over them and not accidentally read spoilers.

Also, the favorites tag will highlight questions that are tagged with one of your Favorited tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wanted to add something to this excellent tip.  If you go into your profile, and then prefs, there's this handy option:

[image: Screenshot of Ignored Tags section of user prefs]

Once you check that box, any questions that have one of your ignored tags on them become utterly invisible to you.  When browsing the site, you will not see them on any of the questions pages.  Very handy for avoiding spoilers.

Comment: Oh, nice. That option should be right on the main page.

Comment: This is outdated and doesn’t work.

Answer (score 7):

This changed at some point and is not in preferences; now the way to hide tags rather than just gray them out is a box on the right side of the homepage:

[image: Ignored tags are just grayed out]

If you click the `Hide questions in your ignored tags` button, they will be hidden now:

[image: They are hidden now]

Comment: But OP is not so regular to change

Comment: @DForck42 hi! Do you think you could accept this answer, so people looking for how to do this see it first instead of the old one that doesn’t work anymore? Thanks!