# Improving the English in the Help section

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Currently the Help reads as such:

> Identify-This-X Questions
>
> Identification questions are currently on-topic for this site. Please try to give as much detail as possible:

```
Where you watched the movie or TV show
When you watched the movie or TV show
Any idea of how old it was
Any idea of country of origin (if known)
Whether it was animated or not
Any distinctive detail
```

> See this question to get a feel of what we expect from a well rounded Identify-This-* question.
>
> Identify-This questions are of limited use to other users of the site, and are asking people to spend some time identifying the Movie or TV show, so it is the responsibility of the person asking the question to try to answer clarifications within a reasonable amount of time, certainly within a day or so.
>
> Identify-This questions may be deleted if it is considered that they are unanswerable and the person asking is not answering clarification comments. Questions from unregistered users unanswered after 2 weeks are liable to be deleted. Questions lacking in research, i.e. if a question is easily answered from an Actor's name on IMDB or Wikipedia will be closed.

There are two "Identify" subheadings, and the first one seems to contradict the "currently on topic" disclaimer.

Also, it should be "these" questions, not "this", and there should be an "it" between Wikipedia and will be closed.

Comment: Yeah, the english is not great - feel free to edit below and when we are happy, then I'll push it back to the help pages.

Comment: There have been no edits for two days, so I took the content below and the changes I was suggesting for the 'off-topic' list from another question and updated the help.  Please ping me if more edits happen.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't I make this answer a community wiki and allow people to edit it until we're happy with it? .....

---

**Movies & TV Stack Exchange** is for Movie & TV enthusiasts and experts alike!

If your question generally covers …

- Analysis of content or theme of all forms of Movies/TV
- Identifying a Movie or TV series (see below for details)
- Questions about a Movie/TV show's production.
- The works of a director / an actor / a writer related to Movies/TV

Movies also includes **Made-For-TV movies**, **Direct-to-DVD**, **Mini-Series** and **short films**.

**Please note that the following subjects are considered *off-topic* here:**

- Distribution
- Movie/TV purchasing/viewing locations
- The operation of playing a movie whether it be digital or physical format.
- Unimportant trivia that does not add to the understanding or appreciation of the title.
- TV news and current affairs
- A title's release date or rumors about a specific title or series.
- Opinions about or recommendations for a movie or TV show

**Spoilers**

Please note that **spoilers are allowed here and may be out in the open.**  Read at your own risk.

The use of spoiler markup should be kept to a minimum, or not used at all if it is clear what Movie or TV Show is being discussed in the question.  Use common sense and apply spoiler markup to cover only aspects of your post that you would think might be unexpected, such as references to other movies.

Spoiler tags will be deleted from questions as nearly every question reveals details about a movie or TV show.

While we encourage you to be aware of spoilers in our questions, we make every effort to remove spoilers from **Question Titles** which is one part of the site that does not have mark-up capabilities and is out in the open.  Also, please refer to this [meta post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/538/you-can-select-tags-to-ignore) on how to keep specific tags from your view.

**Identify-This-X Questions**

Identification questions are currently on-topic for this site.  Please try to give as much detail as possible:

- Where you watched the movie or TV show
- When you watched the movie or TV show
- Any idea of how old it was
- Any idea of country of origin (if known)
- Whether it was animated or not
- Any distinctive detail

See [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8035/which-movie-is-this-no-actor-names-nor-character-names) to get a feel of what we expect from a well rounded Identify-This-* question.

Identification questions are of limited use to other users of the site, and are asking people to spend some time identifying the Movie or TV show, so it is the responsibility of the person asking the question to try to answer clarifications within a reasonable amount of time, certainly within a day or so.

Identification questions may be deleted if it is considered that they are unanswerable and the person asking is not answering clarification comments.   Questions from unregistered users unanswered [*after 2 weeks*](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380/should-we-close-older-identify-questions) are liable to be deleted. Questions lacking in research, i.e. being easily answered from an actor's name on IMDB or Wikipedia, might get closed.

Please [look around](/search) to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](/helpcenter/self-answer).

If your question is not specifically on-topic for Movies & TV Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for [another Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites). If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may [commit to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or [propose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) a new site at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

For more help, see ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](/help/dont-ask)

Comment: What is an *"Identify-These question"* though? Maybe *"Identification question"* would be the more appropriate term.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Now that you state it that way it reads different to me. I was taking the original dash as a separator from the rest of the paragraph, not as a tag representation.

Comment: @JohnP Oh, now I get it (and I guess that's what confused me in the initial question). But in this case the lack of spaces would have been a *severe* formatting problem in the first place.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Fixed it. And I'm still not happy with the way the lack of research sentence reads, but it's closer.

Answer (score 0):

The two subheadings do not contradict each other.  One is saying that a properly asked "Identify-this" question is on-topic.  Another is saying that if you don't properly ask it by following the guidelines, it will be closed.  There's no contradiction there, it's just a rule which you must follow to not have the question deleted.

One thing you're definitely missing is "Identify-This" is a **type** of question.  In that regard, your request to change "this" to "these" is invalid.  You're simply misunderstanding the usage of the word "this" in this case.

The one thing I do agree with is that the word "it" does, in fact, belong between "Wikipedia" and "will be closed" on the last line.

Comment: *"One thing you're definitely missing is "Identify-This" is a type of question. In that regard, your request to change "this" to "these" is invalid. You're simply misunderstanding the usage of the word "this" in this case."* - As has already been *successfully* clarified to him in the comments of the other answer, though.

Comment: Apparently not, because I still don't see it.